# How to set value of the DatePicker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I want to set the date of `DatePicker` value when i click on the set date button but i am getting this error `RangeError Invalid time value`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
export default function App() {
  const my_date = "26/05/2020";
  var [edit_check_date, set_edit_check_date] = React.useState(new Date());

  const set_date = () => {
    set_edit_check_date(my_date);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="submit" value="set date" onClick={set_date} />
      <DatePicker
        dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        className="form-control"
        selected={edit_check_date}
        onChange={date => set_edit_check_date(date)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you did not tell us which library you are using for DatePicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared an example using `react-datepicker`. I dont change any code from your one except I show an `alert` to see the changed date. Here is the complete example:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function DatePickerEx() {
    const [edit_check_date, set_edit_check_date] = useState(new Date());

    const open_modal = record => {
        /* record.check_date value is '25/05/2020' */
        set_edit_check_date(record.check_date); // This is making the error
    };

    function clickHandler(event) {
        const my_date = new Date( "2020-05-26");
        set_edit_check_date(my_date);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <DatePicker
                dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                className="form-control"
                selected={edit_check_date}
                onChange={date => {
                    set_edit_check_date(date);
                    alert(date);
                }}
            />
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Set 2020-05-26</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-bird-uyfm9)

**Update**

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    let date = "26/05/2020";
    let my_date = new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
    console.log(date);
    console.log(my_date);
    set_edit_check_date(my_date);
}
```

Comment: My problem is that i want to set the value of the date form a the record instead of selecting it from the clendar box

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer as well as `code sand box` that I provided with answer. Please check it

Comment: Thank you but since the date format i have is in this format `DD/MM/YYYY` and it making error when try to `set_edit_check_date('26/05/2020`);`

Comment: you have convert your format to the format that accepts Date object

Comment: please can you show how to do that, i tried to change it using `moment.js` but didn't work